# Solution Verification for combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Question: You go into a supermarket to buy 2 packets of biscuits, which may or may not be of the same variety. The supermarket has 20 different varieties of biscuits and at least two packets of each variety. In how many ways can you choose your two packets?

My solution: You have 20 choices for both the first and second picks as there are at least 2 packets of each variety so the answer should be 400.

I saw someone post a solution online to this problem where they claimed the answer was 210 so there may be something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am curious as to how they got to 210. Unless the number of packets of each variety enters in consideration (but it is not given so I assume it is just the variety that we pick twice).

If it is the variety that is picket twice (there is no additional info) then the result is indeed 400.

Comment: If you buy Biscuit A and Biscuit B, then the online solution see this as the same as buying Biscuit B and Biscuit A, while you would count this as two distinct possibilities (assuming A and B differ)

Comment: Thanks, that's something I completely missed. I always forget to check for double-counted solutions.